# What do you call an object that can have duplicate elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Lets say I have a list: $L:=(a,b,c,d)$ of objects from some space. I can call $L$ as set iff each element is unique, otherwise, the set associated with $L$ will have fewer elements than L.

Is there a mathematical term for $L$: a collection of objects that may or may not be unique?

Comment: Google for multiset

Comment: In computer science it is often called a *bag*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the notion of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks so much. Ill accept in 13 minutes.